# Unable to boot archlinux image from usb

Tags: arch-linux, boot, iso

I have come across with an installation problem and I want to use the usb boot option to rescue my machine. I formatted the usb to be `fat32` and execute the command `dd bs=4M if=/path/to/archlinux.iso of=/dev/sdx status=progress && sync`. Everything went well and as far as I know, if I boot using UEFI this should be the steps to follow.

However, on booting I have:

```
Arch Linux archiso x86_64 UEFI CD
UEFI Shell x86_64_v1
UEFI Shell x86_64_v2
EFI Default Loader
Reboot Into Firmware Interface
```

I think I should select option number 1, but this reboots the machine and I end up again in the same menu. I know there should be everything fine with the `EFI` stuff, because that's how I installed archlinux. I checked the bios and I also see that it is nothing in secure mode (usb).

Comment: To complete the question, I have my boot mode set to `UEFI with Legacy OPROM; Secure boot: OFF`

Comment: Could you try without "Legacy OPROM"?

Comment: I Johan, I figured out what at least solved the problem. I will post it. Thanks nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

For all that you may suffer a similar thing, I solved it as follows.

It appears that formatting the usb with `FAT32` is not enough. I reformatted the usb with `cfdisk` and looked at the available options. From all of them,
near the bottom, there is one that says `EFI...` which also says that it is `FAT 16/32...`. That's the one that one have to select and then everything works (at least for me).